# About resultset type JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

In [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) oracle java tutorial, it says:

> TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY: The result set cannot be scrolled; its cursor moves
>   forward only, from before the first row to after the last row. The
>   rows contained in the result set depend on how the underlying database
>   generates the results. That is, it contains the rows that satisfy the
>   query at either the time the query is executed or as the rows are
>   retrieved.

"*The rows contained in the result set depend on how the underlying database generates the results.*"

What's the difference between the query execution time and rows retrieving time?
And how can I know which my database supports?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the difference between eager and lazy loading.  I'd recommend researching those terms.

Eager loading means all the results are made available at once.  It could require a great deal of time and memory if the set is large.

Lazy loading doles out results as needed.  It's along the lines of what Google does when you search for pages: they'll find millions, but only return them 25 at time with higher ranks first.